# How to write a JS code which will print Fibonacci series where End value is not greater than 33. (e.g. 0112358)

Tags: javascript

Write a JS code which will print Fibonacci series where End value is not greater than 33. (e.g. 0112358)

```
    var n=10;
function fib(n){
    var a=[];
    a[0]=0;
    a[1]=1;
    for(i=2;i<n;i++){
        a[i]=a[i-1]+a[i-2];
    }
    return a;
}
console.log(fib(n));
```

Comment: Show us what you tried. Stackoverflow isn't a free homework or code writing service. See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Read the link chat @charlietfl provided. You have not described the problem yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```js
function fib(n){
  var a = 0;
  var b = 1;
  var c = 0;
  document.write(a+" "+b);
  for(var i = 2; i < n; i++){
    c = a + b
    if(c > 33)
      break;
    a = b;
    b  = c;
    document.write(" "+c);
  }
}

fib(10);
```

Comment: I have attached a code by using your concept. I want to know about is there any more efficient way to do this task.

Answer (score 0):

I get this solution by using array. but what is efficient way to this task.

```
function fib(n) {
        var arr=[];
        var a,b,c;
        a=0;
        b=1;

        arr.push(a);
        arr.push(b);

        while((a+b)<n){
            c=a+b;
            a=b;
            b=c;        
            arr.push(c);
        }

        return arr;
    }

    console.log(fib(33));
```